# Wsutil.exe (Native Web Services Compiler): WCHAR* vs LPCWSTR for xsd:string type

Tags: wchar, lpcwstr

Is there a good reason for the native web services compiler to generate a `WCHAR *` for an `xsd:string` vs a `const wchar_t*` (or LPCWSTR in short)?

The reason I state this question is that ours is a native c++ application which has `std::wstring`s floating around in the code that needs to be passed into a WCF service. In order to use the C functions generated by the native web services compiler it's forcing me to do something on the lines of e.g.

```
MyCppFunc(const std::wstring& inputString ,…)
{
… 
    HRESULT hr = BasicHttpBinding_BlahService(const_cast<<WCHAR*>WCHAR*>(inputString.c_str()), ….); 
}
```

As seen from above I am forced to do away with the `const` on the pointer, my point of concern here is by explicitly having a `WCHAR*` type is the pointer data expected to get manipulated by the webservices.lib itself in anyway?

Alternatively I could end up copying over the contents of the string to a `WCHAR*` but for the fact that our c++ app runs as a service and we have heap fragmentation concerns over the frequent allocations/de-allocations.

Thanks.,
Raghu